Is there any difference of meaning in these 3 sentencess
I am going to receive the book in two weeks.
I am receiving the book in two weeks.
I will be receiving the book in two weeks .
I think they all have the same meaning. The action in all cases has been planned and has not been done  yet. Going to seems less sure than am receiving and will be receiving .
Am I right?

Yes, they all have the same meaning.

Is the first one idiomatic ?

Note, part of the reason they come out the same is the "in two weeks." Delete that, and the present progressive is interpreted as, well, present.

They all have the same meaning and all are idiomatic.
However, we usually use "I am [verb]ing" of things that we plan to do ourselves. You could say "They are sending me the book in two weeks", but "I am receiving it" sounds slightly less natural to me.

Why I am receiving it sounds less natural . Is it because when we receive we dont make the action

"Why does 'I am receiving it' sound less natural?" Assuming that the book will be sent by post, the exact time that I receive it is outside my control. (I know the same applies to the other two sentences, but I did say that it sounds slightly less natural to me.)

Change "book" to "award": "I'm receiving tne award in two weeks" and it's fine. If a book is arriving by mail or via interlibrary loan, "I'm receiving the book" is not the way most people would phrase the sentence.  They'd make "book" the subject.  The book is arriving in two weeks.   Or "I should be receiving the book in two weeks."   "am receiving" is too definite for the situation.
